# Getting started with Flyway and an existing PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, flyway

I read the article related to [Existing database setup](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/existing) but I still didn't get it.

I already have a postgresql database with a lot of data, and I would like to have a migration tool to keep track of my database schema. From what I understand from that link (in my case, using postgresql) I just have to do "pg_dump -s ..." (which will dump schemas, tables, ... but not data from tables, in sql format), name it as "V1__Baseline_version.sql" and add it to the /sql directory. This will be the baseline version for my existent database:

```
$ flyway baseline -Dflyway.baselineVersion=1 -Dflyway.baselineDescription="Base version"
```

The above command will create an additional table in my database to keep track of migrations.

**Note:** I don't want to add any reference data, just to keep track of db schema changes

Now, any new changes to my schema should be added for example to /sql/V2__Add_some_changes.sql and run:

```
$ flyway migrate
```

and this will migrate my existing database to V2.

... and so on, V3 ...Vx

Can somebody confirm that it is the right approach?

Edit: one more question: Having multiple machines, development/testing/staging/production I can use the same set of sql scripts (stored in one common /sql) to keep their db schema in "sync", and just do for each: "flyway baseline ..." + "flyway migrate".

Comment: @markdsievers, asked one more thing :)

Comment: Yes exactly right. `baseline` you just need to run once, that effectively says "this SQL file is equivalent to the current database schema". `migrate` will run any migration files that have not yet been run. This [how documentation](https://flywaydb.org/getstarted/how) shows the `schema_version` table which might help you visualize how Flyway works. `info` is another useful command which tells you what has been run and also what *will* be run if you ran `migrate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for additional information!